# OnTextChanged not firing event

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to fire an OnTextChanged event, but it is not working.

Textbox code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="regSponsor" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
             OnTextChanged="regSponsor_TextChanged" required="required" 
             class="form-control" placeholder="Sponsor ID">
</asp:TextBox>
```

CS code:

```
protected void regSponsor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Data inserted successfully')</script>");
}
```

Autopostback is set to true and I understand that ontextchanged only works when the textbox loses focus, but still it is not working.

Is there any thing I miss out?

Comment: do you have only one textbox in page?? and have you tried changing values before it looses focus?

Comment: @RohitS There are multiple textboxes on this page, but only one with OnTextChanged. Yes, I tried changing values before making it looses focus.

Comment: sorry for late reply but you can check out console in that case for any errors

Comment: Did you actually change the value in the textbox?